# MathJax is not defined

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have successfully loaded and configured MathJax by pasting MathJax recommended commands into the `<head>` element of my webpage.  MathJax does a great job rendering LaTex in the `<body>` of my webpage.

My problem is with accessing the `MathJax` object with javascript run at the very end of the `<body>` element.  For instance, the code below returns `undefined` to the console.  This is confusing to me- shouldn't my commands in the `<head>` element have created `MathJax`as a global variable that can be accessed anywhere?

Here's a screenshot of my code:
[image: code screenshot]

Here is the relevant section of code from the `<head>` element:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
    src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">
</script>
```

Here is the relevant section of code from the `<body>` element:

```
<h1 class="header">
    If $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.
</h1>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    console.log(window.MathJax);
</script>
```

Comment: Your script includes are out of order. You need to include the MathJax script before referencing it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thank you, however the problem is with the script on lines 25:27, not with the order of the scripts in the `<head>` element.  (I agree that the order of the scripts in the `<head>` element would make more sense reversed, however I have copied them as they are straight from [http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html](MathJax.org), and they seem to be working fine.)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are loading `MathJax.js` with the [`async` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). Therefore, the browser does not block rendering until the script has loaded but instead continues to process the page. So now you have a race between `MathJax.js` getting fetched and loaded vs the browser's parser getting to the `script` tag further down in the page. Inevitably, the parser wins and executes the log before `MathJax.js` has finished loading. Accordingly, there is no global `MathJax` object.

If you remove `async`, then the browser will first execute `MathJax.js` before parsing the remaining page and thus the `console.log` will provide something meaningful. (Similarly, on older browsers which do not support the `async` attribute, you will get a result.)

Note, however, that MathJax is highly asynchronous in itself (loading additional components, configurations etc) so you will most likely need to [synchronize your code with MathJax's APIs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/synchronize.html).